# Spring Hibernate Jpa error: root cause java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown parameter position: 1

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Hi I am getting following error.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown parameter position: 1]
>   with root cause java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown parameter
>   position: 1   at
>   org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingsImpl.getBinding(QueryParameterBindingsImpl.java:240)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.setParameter(AbstractProducedQuery.java:503)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.setParameter(AbstractProducedQuery.java:104)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:372)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy63.setParameter(Unknown Source)  at
>   edu.zipcloud.cloudstreetmarket.core.daos.HistoricalIndexRepositoryImpl.findLastHistoric(HistoricalIndexRepositoryImpl.java:37)
>     at
>   edu.zipcloud.cloudstreetmarket.core.daos.HistoricalIndexRepositoryImpl.findLastIntraDay(HistoricalIndexRepositoryImpl.java:31)
>     at
>   edu.zipcloud.cloudstreetmarket.core.services.MarketServiceImpl.getLastDayIndexActivity(MarketServiceImpl.java:41)
>     at
>   edu.zipcloud.cloudstreetmarket.portal.controllers.DefaultController.fallBack(DefaultController.java:26)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)

inside method `findLastHistoric(HistoricalIndexRepositoryImpl.java:37)`

class:

```
@Repository
public class HistoricalIndexRepositoryImpl implements HistoricalIndexRepository{

    @PersistenceContext 
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public Iterable<HistoricalIndex> findIntraDay(String code, Date of) {
        TypedQuery<HistoricalIndex> sqlQuery = em.createQuery("from HistoricalIndex h where h.index.code = ? and h.fromDate >= ? and h.toDate <= ? ORDER BY h.toDate asc", HistoricalIndex.class);
        sqlQuery.setParameter(1, code);
        sqlQuery.setParameter(2, DateUtil.getStartOfDay(of));
        sqlQuery.setParameter(3, DateUtil.getEndOfDay(of));
        return sqlQuery.getResultList();
    }

    @Override
    public Iterable<HistoricalIndex> findLastIntraDay(String code) {
        return findIntraDay(code, findLastHistoric(code).getToDate());
    }

    @Override
    public HistoricalIndex findLastHistoric(String code){
        TypedQuery<HistoricalIndex> sqlQuery = em.createQuery("from HistoricalIndex h where h.index.code = ? ORDER BY h.toDate desc", HistoricalIndex.class);
        sqlQuery.setParameter(1, code);
        return sqlQuery.setMaxResults(1).getSingleResult();
    }
}
```

Please help me to resolve this error. If you need other information, let me know.

Regards.

Comment: you are using HQL? If yes try to use `from HistoricalIndex h where h.index.code = :code ORDER BY h.toDate desc`
and while setting the parameter, use `sqlQuery.setParameter("code", code);`

Comment: yes Sir @zombie

Comment: Oh dear. seems to have forgotten the "SELECT {alias}" from queries. Also JPA uses POSITIONAL PARAMETERS (or NAMED PARAMETERS), not JDBC syntax. Read basic JPA docs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
    TypedQuery<HistoricalIndex> sqlQuery = em.createQuery("from HistoricalIndex h where h.index.code = ?1 ORDER BY h.toDate desc", HistoricalIndex.class);
```

Check [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/) section 5.3.2. Query creation